# JS regular expression to match imdb url

Tags: javascript

Can any one tell me what is wrong with this javascript code

```
"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2618986/".match("~http://(?:.*\.|.*)imdb.com/(?:t|T)itle(?:\?|/)(..\d+)~i");
```

When i try this here https://regex101.com/r/yT7bG4/1 it works but not in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you create a regular expression in JavaScript is `/pattern/flags`. The code you are looking for is something along the lines of:

```
"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2618986/".match(/http:\/\/(?:.*\.|.*)imdb.com\/(?:t|T)itle(?:\?|\/)(..\d+)/i);
```

You have to escape all of the `/` in the regular expression so the `/` become part of the regular expression instead of indicating the end of it. I would suggest reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) if you want to learn more about regular expressions in JavaScript.

Also, https://regex101.com/ has a JavaScript option on the left, under the 'FLAVOR' banner, which may help knowing which flags are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are using pcre(php) flavor in regex101. You should select javascript flavor.

Considers that there is not '~' delimiter in javascript RegExp. This is why your code is not working.

You should write something like:

```
"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2618986/".match(/http:\/\/(?:.*\.|.*)\.imdb.com\/(?:t|T)itle(?:\?|\/)(..\d+)/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

- / symbol must be escapes - like this /.
- there is not '~' delimiter

Result code with regular expression is:

```
"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2618986/".match(/http:\/\/(?:.*\.|.*)imdb.com\/title(?:\?|\/)(..\d+)/i)
```

p.s. use modifier 'i' to do a case-insensitive search